# Link to "show single-entity": Is the necessary to use the entity_path helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently my code looks this way:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <li><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></li>
<% end %>
```

But if I do ...

```
...
<li><%= link_to post.title, post %></li>
...
```

... the hyperlink becomes created and works as well. No difference.

**Should I use the helper-function nevertheless? And if so: Why?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The later uses the [polymorphic route helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) which are extremely useful and widely used in the framework:

> Polymorphic URL helpers are methods for smart resolution to a named
> route call when given an Active Record model instance. They are to be
> used in combination with ActionController::Resources.
>
> These methods are useful when you want to generate the correct URL or
> path to a RESTful resource without having to know the exact type of
> the record in question.

If you take the common example where you have comments attached to various types of resources for example you can generate a link with:

```
link_to 'All comments', [commentable, :comments]
```

We don't need to know if `commentable` is a `Video` or `Post` or write wonky code that calls `video_comments_path` or `post_comments_path` depending on the type.

Another really common use in Rails is forms. When you use `form_with/form_for` it uses the routing helpers to set the correct action for creating or updating a resource.

In this specific case it does not really matter. The performance cost of using the polymorphic route helpers is trivial and IMHO being explicit really just adds noise.

Since Rails is driven by convention over configuration you really only need to be explicit if you're going off the Rails. No Rails developer worth their salt should have any problems figuring out what `<%= link_to post.title, post %>` does.

Comment: The documentation quoted is actually slightly wrong/outdated - the polymorphic route helpers work with any ActiveModel backed model - not just ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is that link_to will handle the route "conversion" depending in the type of object you're passing to its options argument:

```
def link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
  html_options, options, name = options, name, block if block_given?
  options ||= {}

  html_options = convert_options_to_data_attributes(options, html_options)

  url = url_for(options) # <- HERE
  html_options["href"] ||= url

  content_tag("a", name || url, html_options, &block)
end
```

So, if you pass the URL already generated, meaning, the string e.g. "/posts/1" it'll call `url_for` using that object as the argument and then it'll return the same. While if you pass the "whole" post object, it'll take care of invoking `url_for` with that object and the result will be the same.

When you generate a scaffold in Rails, the `link_to`s generated use your second version. I assume that's because there's no need for such vervbosity, and the less code you write, the better.

Anyway, any answer for that'd be a personal preference. So do it how you think is better for you, your codebase, your team, etc.

Answering to your question; "Is it necessary to use the entity_path helper?", as we saw, it is not.